# Postgres fulltextsearch with more than one word in one column

Tags: postgresql, select, tsvector

I want to create a fulltext select query on a postgres database.
For example I want to find all books with title "Harry Potter". If I just look up for Harry with the fulltext search it runs fast.
e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE to_tsvector('simple', cast(title AS text)) @@ plainto_tsquery('simple',cast('harry' AS text))
```

But if I try to combine a title like Harry Potter, my query is running out of time (like one minute)

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE to_tsvector('simple', cast(title AS text)) @@ plainto_tsquery('simple',cast('harry' AS text)) AND to_tsvector('simple', cast(title AS text)) @@ plainto_tsquery('simple',cast('potter' AS text))
```

What is my mistake? I need this fulltextsearch also a combination of 1 or more words.

If there exists a better solution than to combine two words in one query like

```
 SELECT * FROM books WHERE to_tsvector('simple', cast(title AS text)) @@ plainto_tsquery('simple',cast('harry potter' AS text))
```

EDIT: Found something:
The count of my Harry Potter is about 110.000 datas (actually like 1 mio data in books).
If I look up for e.g. Ice Fire there are just 300 results in database and my query is running sooo fast. 
Maybe its a problem about the resultset getting back from the database?
I actually using limit 100.

Comment: "If there exists a better solution than to combine two words in one query like": 'Better' in what way?  Is combining them in one query still slow?  In that case, post an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) of it.  Or is it fast, but you just find it ugly for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a phrase search:

```
WHERE to_tsvector('simple', title) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'harry <-> potter')
```

Comment: Same high responsetime :/

Comment: Then you need a GIN index on `to_tsvector('simple', title)`.

Comment: I added a GIN index. Is the query still the same?  ```SELECT * FROM books WHERE to_tsvector('simple', cast(title AS text)) @@ plainto_tsquery('simple',cast('harry potter' AS text))```?

Comment: The indexed expression must be exactly the same as the expression left of the `@@`. Use `EXPLAIN` to find out if the index is used.

Comment: GIN works finde, but still have another problem. Doing new Ticket I guess.